# How to add custom confirm box on page refresh in Angular5?

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote some code which will show me a confirm dialog based on a flag stored in my browser's local Storage.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('visitedPage') == 'true') {
  this.alertService.confirmThis("Are you sure?",function(){
    console.log("Yes");
  },function(){
    console.log("No");
  })
} else {
  localStorage.setItem('visitedPage','true');
}
```

But I can see that dialog only after the page refresh (the entire content goes off, the page loads & the dialog opens). But I need that dialog immediately on hitting refresh.

Any suggestions or examples please!!

Comment: you want dialog on browser refersh button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in angular if you want to capture event of refresh you can do like this

```
//this should be parent component , in your case it should be app.component

@Component({ 
  selector: 'xxx',
  ..
)}
class MyComponent {
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload',['$event'])
  showMessage($event) {
     $event.returnValue='Your data will be lost!';
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added my dialog instead of alert(). But it is just coming and the page gets refreshed.

Comment: @Krishna - so you want to stop page from refresh ??

Comment: Yes. I want user to confirm whether to refresh or not @Pranay

Comment: Thanks. Its working. Can I change the default javascript confirm box? Or atleast Can I change the text over there

Comment: @Krishna - you can experiment it as i never did it , please do accept upvote if worked for you